# google datastore query with embedded collection of items

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore, gql

We have a Kind containing objects like the following example stored in google datastore. (firestore in datastore mode now)

```
{
"id": "xxx"
"date": "xxx"
"array": [
        {
            "itemid": "xxx"
            "param1": "xxx"
            "subarray": [
                {
                    "subparam1": "xxx",
                    "subparam2": "xxx",
                },
                {
                    "subparam1": "xxx",
                    "subparam2": "xxx",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "itemid": "xxx",
            "param1": "xxx",
            "subarray": [
                {
                    "subparam1": "xxx",
                    "subparam2": "xxx",
                },
                {
                    "subparam1": "xxx",
                    "subparam2": "xxx",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

what is the best way to:

- retrieve a list of subarray for a given id and where date>datetime("2021-10-19T20:00:00.00000+02:00") in the form

> id / date / subarray_content

- retrieve a list of subparam1 for a given id and where date>datetime("2021-10-19T20:00:00.00000+02:00") in the form

> id / data / itemid / subparam1

can they be expressed in GQL?

what indexes should be created for them?

(yes it is easy to retrieve objects matching id and criteria on date and filter the results programmatically but it is not very efficient)

thanks

Comment: Check if for your first case something like `SELECT id, date, array.subarray FROM [your_kind] WHERE id = [your_id] AND date > [your_desired_datetime];` Also, for indexes, whenever you run a query and it ends up requiring indexes, the error message will tell you which indexes you have to create in order for it to work.